# Executing command on VM inside VMware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

Is there any way to execute command on a virtual machine from VMWare server console?

I am able to get the list of VMs by using the command `esxcli vm process list`. Can I execute command on the VM without doing SSH to VM seperatly?

Answer (score 0):

using vmrun tool: see ref: [vmrun command](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_vmrun_command.pdf)

e.g.:
vmrun -T ws -gu  runScriptInGuest Win2k\Win2k.vmx C:\perl\perl.exe C:\script.pl